# Hidden ul elements on load, display on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create some sort of menu.
I have managed to create "collapsing" ul elements, but can't figure out how to set ul elements to be hidden on load

```
         <ul>
        <li class="error">Displayed</li>
        <ul>
           <li class="error">Hidden</li>
              <ul>
                 <li class="error">
                    <a href="test.html">Hidden</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>              
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

jquery

```
$(".error").click(function () {
$(this).next("ul").toggle("slow");});
```

here is my sample with collapsing ul elements http://jsbin.com/povafivu/1/edit?html,js,output

Thanks

Comment: define id or class to ul then apply css on display none.

Comment: Use CSS to hide it by default, don't use JS. Otherwise you'll get the awesome ["flash of unstyled content"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/povafivu/4/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul").children('.error').next('ul').hide();
});
```

Button click show 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> ul

```
$("button").click(function(){
 $("ul").children('.error').next('ul').toggle("slow").next('ul').toggle("slow");
})
```

Button code `<button>test</button>` [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/povafivu/10/edit)

Comment: is it possible to modify function to display second and third ul in the same time? With one click

Comment: do you know why "slow" animation is not applying to last ul? Thanks, this really helped

Comment: @sevdah animation is applying of last ul but we can't see it because of first is not completed. We can use callback for this solution in in this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/povafivu/12/edit)

Answer (score 5):

Why not use css to hide it by default?

```
ul > ul > li {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: i am not sure why, but when added this code, ul elements remain hidden on click

Comment: Yes you will then need to show them by adding a class on click or using the `toggle()` function.

Comment: I am already using toggle to hide ul, but when added ul > ul > li {
  display: none;} toggle functio is not working correctly. Maybe i made mistake somewhere http://jsbin.com/povafivu/8/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thats a different question regarding how to achieve what you are aiming for. What exactly are you looking to get at the end of it, a dropdown menu with multiple levels?

Answer (score 0):

use css3

```
ul > ul > li:nth-of-type(1)
    {
 display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply set the ul element display to none initially. and toggle it wen required.